# how to calculate percentage difference in sql reporting 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a scenario where I'm showing weekly prices as a column group and I want a column where I will display the average of daily percentage difference. I want to know is there a way in sql server reporting service 2008 R2 or do I have to manually create in my query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly, your current query is only returning results aggregated at the weekly level of granularity.

Possible solution not requiring an aggregated SQL query:

- Modify your query to return data at the daily level of granularity.
- Use a combination of Grouping and Calculated fields (and hiding) to obtain the "Average Daily Percent Difference", but to hide the daily prices if you do not want to display them.

Assuming "Average Daily Percent Difference" is referring to the average of the daily percent change between prices for a single week, the best solution is to write an aggregated SQL query instead.